# Get the current request from a RequestContext?

Tags: django

Does a Django `RequestContext` have a way to get the `HttpRequest` object with which it is associated with? Does it have a method like `get_request()` or the like to get the `request` which is passed into the constructor? I need to reference it from a method in which I only receive the `RequestContext`.

Comment: A little late to the party, and this comes with the disclaimer that I'm just now getting into Django, but when you pass the dict argument to `RequestContext` you could potentially add `'request': request` and then retrieve it with context.get('request').  It doesn't feel right really, and it would require you to change your views to pass it in, but if you really needed it you could do that.  Also, if you find another (better) way, please update. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings. And get request where context is available using :

```
request = context['request']
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the `django.template.RequestContext` (which lives in `django/template/context.py`) does not store any reference to the request object:

```
class RequestContext(Context):
    """
    This subclass of template.Context automatically populates itself using
    the processors defined in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.
    Additional processors can be specified as a list of callables
    using the "processors" keyword argument.
    """
    def __init__(self, request, dict=None, processors=None, current_app=None, use_l10n=None):
        Context.__init__(self, dict, current_app=current_app, use_l10n=use_l10n)
        if processors is None:
            processors = ()
        else:
            processors = tuple(processors)
        for processor in get_standard_processors() + processors:
            self.update(processor(request))
```

If Django were patched to include a simple line like this in the constructor:

```
self.request = request
```

and a function definition like this:

```
def get_request(self):
     return self.request
```

then we'd be in business. Unfortunately, we're not, so the answer is "No, you can't get the request object associated with a `RequestContext`."

Comment: Just for readers that stumble upon this in 2014, like me: Hanson's answer is the right one, the accepted answer is wrong. Just add django.core.context_processors.request to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Comment: @Bunkerbewohner I'll accept his answer above, as mine is out of date. This question was originally asked in 2011 and Django has changed since then.